# subprocess window disappear quickly

Tags: python, windows

In python, I use subprocess.Popen() to launch several processes, I want to debug those processes, but the windows of those processes disappeared quickly and I got no chance to see the error message. I would like to know whether there is any way I can stop the window from disappearing or write the contents in the windows to a file so that I can see the error message later.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

you can use the stdout and stderr arguments to write the outputs in a file.
example:

```
with open("log.txt", 'a') as log:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', 'args'], stdout=log, stderr=log)
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, the common way of keeping cmd windows opened after the end of a console process is to use `cmd /k`

Example : in a cmd window, typing `start cmd /k echo foo`

- opens a new window (per `start`)
- displays the output `foo`
- leave the command window opened

Comment: Escaping commands to pass through cmd.exe can be difficult and (AFAICT) even sometimes impossible. If python.exe is available I'd use that instead. Assuming the command line or list is in `args`, you could use the following: `python = sys.executable.replace('pythonw.exe', 'python.exe');` `subprocess.call([python, '-i', '-c', 'import subprocess; rc = subprocess.call(%r)' % args], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`. The new console window will remain open in Python's REPL.

Comment: @eryksun : CreateProcess API only knows the executable file and one single command line string (LPCTSTR), so escaping is usually not a real problem in Windows. But I think that your method seems really nice, and you could make it an answer

Comment: cmd.exe parses the command line before calling `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx` -- to which it may make several calls if it tokenizes the command line into multiple commands to be executed.

Comment: BTW, to clarify terms it's not a "cmd window". The cmd shell, like any console process, is attached to a console host. The console window is hosted by conhost.exe (Win 7+), or csrss.exe in older systems. Client-side APIs such as `ReadConsole`, `SetConsoleCP`, and `AddConsoleAlias` use either LPC (Win 7) or a console device (Win 8) to talk to the host/server. The host process manages command line editing, history, aliases, and console control events for all processes attached to a given console.